# Associativity in JavaScript classes

Tags: java, javascript, entity

I am new to this and would be grateful if someone can help me out here.

I am trying to recreate the entity classes in Java to JavaScript because of a project requirement.

One question that remains is how to recreate the association or dependencies between the Java entities in JavaScript.

For example.
Lets say I created an entity employee with the following fields

Employee: eId, eName, rId(Associated with the rId of Role Entity)
Role: rId, rName.

Now how to do the same with JavaScript creating two file employee.js and role.js ?

Comment: You would create a Javascript [OBJECT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Example.3A_Using_Object_to_create_Boolean_objects) with those properties.

Comment: Do you really need the Java classes as JavaScript objects or that's your current (or imposed) proposed solution? If the latter, please edit your question and explain the real problem to have better guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like this

```
function Role(roleId, roleName) {
    this.id = roleId;
    this.roleName = roleName;
    Role.roles[roleId] = this;
}
Role.roles = {};

function Employee(employeeId, employeeName, roleId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
    this.roleId = roleId;
}
Employee.prototype = Object.create(null, {
    role: {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        get: function () {return Role.roles[this.roleId];},
        set: function (role) {return Role.roles[this.roleId = role.id]}
    }
});

var man   = new Role(0, 'Romeo'),
    woman = new Role(1, 'Juliet');
var actor   = new Employee(0, 'John Smith', 0),
    actress = new Employee(1, 'Jane Doe', 1);

actor;      // Employee {employeeId: 0, employeeName: "John Smith", roleId: 0}
actor.role; // Role {id: 0, roleName: "Romeo"} === Role.roles[0];
```

Comment: What if we have the function Role in role.js and the function employee in employee.js

Comment: @HemanthSJ Look how it is written for references to one in the other; _Role_ has no dependencies on _Employee_ so will work fine without it. _Employee_ only has references to _Role_ in `Employee.prototype.roll`, so everything except that will work (_Employee_ will still construct even without _Role_ defined).

Answer (score -1):

You should create JavaScript Objects, like this.

```
var employee = {eId: 1, rId: 1};
var role = {rId: 1, rName: 'Role'};
```